# node.js - use template engine to return html

Tags: node.js, template-engine

So i have a node.js app that's using *express* and *ejs* to render templates. I know that by using `res.render()` in my app object i can send a rendered response. But is there any way to just **use** the render engine to get the output'ed html?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to look at [the expressjs documentation for the Response object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res). Response.render is define like that: `res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])`. By supplying a callback function in the form of `function(err, html)`, the render engine will call your callback function with the html string instead of sending it directly to the server.